# Why is sizeof giving me this result?

Tags: c++

I have this code

```
struct Student {
char name[48];
float grade;
int marks[10,5];
char gender;
};

Student s;
```

Now I have to get the sizeof s

so I added

```
printf("%d",sizeof(s));
```

now when I hit compile the result showing is 256

and its wrong because it shoud be 253

as because the size of

char name[48];  ----> 48

and

float grade; -----> 4

and

int marks[10,5]; ------> 200

and

char gender; ------->1

so 48+4+200+1 = 253

so why is it telling me 256?

================================

this part is written after I saw your answers

I learned that

Suppose I have this structure: 
    struct  {
        char a[3];
        short int b;
        long int c;
        char d[3];
        };

So ..

```
+-------+-------+-------+

|           a           |

+-------+-------+-------+

|       b       |

+-------+-------+-------+-------+

|               c               |

+-------+-------+-------+-------+

|           d           |

+-------+-------+-------+
```

In the `packed'' version, notice how it's at least a little bit hard for you and me to see how the b and c fields wrap around? In a nutshell, it's hard for the processor, too. Therefore, most compilers will`pad'' the structure (as if with extra, invisible fields) like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+

|           a           | pad1  |

+-------+-------+-------+-------+

|       b       |     pad2      |

+-------+-------+-------+-------+

|               c               |

+-------+-------+-------+-------+

|           d           | pad3  |

+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

so if Im having the maximum size is 200 should the padding be like

48 + 152

4 + 196

200 + 0

1 + 199

to make them in a perfect shape

Comment: Do you mean `int marks[10][5];`?

Comment: Note that the result of `sizeof` is of type `size_t`, which is unsigned.  You should cast the result to `unsigned int` and print it using the `%u` format specifier.

Comment: Now that you know what happens you can see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment why.

Comment: @hiba: `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(float)` are not necessarily 4.

Comment: Regarding your last edit, it will never pad it "48 + 152 and 4 + 196" even if we assume your largest block is 200 bytes (which is not). It will pad up to the largest primitive type, but it will not pad each field individually. For example, if you have a struct {short;long long}, largest is 8 so the short (2B) will be padded 6B. However if your struct was {short; short; long long}, the structure will still be a total of 16B since there is only 4B padding after the 2 shorts ... i.e. the momory will look like this:
ff ff ff ff
00 00 00 00
ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff
Where f's are vars and 0's padding

Comment: Wanted to add something else, but ran out of chars ... It is important to rearrange you structs to save space. a struct {short; long long; short} will be 3*8 bytes. A struct {short; short; long long} will be 2*8 bytes. This is because the long long breaks the shorts so each short will have to be padded 6 bytes in the first case, while they will be padded a total of 4 bytes in the second case.

Comment: @ Rado thanx a lot I understand it now 100% because of you ( you used a simple language and that what i was looking for )

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There may be padding bytes between the members of the struct or at the end of the struct.

In this case, it is likely that there are three bytes of padding at the end of the struct, after the single char member, to ensure that the size of the struct is a multiple of four.

Comment: +1: word alignment is definitely a reasonable culprit. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment (hiba salem: 1 word = 4 bytes)

Comment: @Bears will eat you: Yes, we should be more worried about bears eating us than 3 bytes extra used space due to alignment issues. ;)

Comment: @James: There should be no padding between elements, it's a POD type.

Comment: @GMan:  "Note:  There might therefore be unnamed padding within a POD-struct object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment."  (9.2/17).

Comment: @GMan: the compiler is free to put padding between members (even of a POD type) if it needs to or even it it just wants to.

Comment: @James @Michael: Hm, what of 1.7/5 then? I must be understanding "contiguous storage" wrong then. Allowing it does make obvious sense with little thought though.

Comment: @GMan:  My interpretation of 1.8/5:  The object must occupy a single contiguous block of memory.  The members subobjects all have to be contained within that contiguous block, but they themselves do not need to be contiguous (i.e. there can be padding between them, as 9.2/17 says).  There are a few interesting discussions on comp.std.c++ if you search for "contiguous bytes."

Comment: @GMan: also note the difference in language for PODs: "bytes of contiguous storage" in 1.8/5, against arrays: "contiguously-allocated non-empty set of N sub-objects" in 8.3.4/1. I've always taken the latter to mean that the sub-objects have no gaps between them, and the former only to mean that the bytes which make up the object have no gaps between them: sub-objects of PODs aren't "contiguous". Since later-declared class members have higher addresses than earlier ones (9.2/12), alignment demands padding in e.g. `struct A { int a; char b; int c; }` on ARM. c's address cannot be unaligned.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler pads the struct to align to a word boundary. It's easier for the processor to handle chunks of 256 bytes than an odd number like 253.

Comment: It has to do with the position of individual elements rather than the size as a whole. If the struct had three chars, and nothing else, the odd size would likely be ignored.

Comment: @Dennis:  The size of the complete struct matters as well, since one can have an array of some struct type and there can be no padding between elements in an array.

Comment: That is still based on the alignment requirements of the individual members. I didn't word it well, but what I was trying to get across is that the compiler doesn't want the size to be a multiple of four just for the sake of having a multiple of four. If 2-byte alignment is good enough for int and float, it might pad to a multiple of 2. If float requires 6-byte alignment, it will pad accordingly.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily align it to a word boundary. It depends on the size of the largest primitive component

Comment: No, it is whatever is neccessary to satisfy the most stringent allignment requirement. This need not correspond to the largest data member.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: Then how do you explain this result with VC++ 2008: struct{_2B ; _8B;} results in 
00 00 ff ff
ff ff ff ff
00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00
, while struct{_2B; _4B; _4B} results in 
00 00 ff ff
00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 
?
#pragma pack(show)==8 ... for the bytes above, padded bytes are ff since i memsetted the struct to 0xff, then assigned 0 to the individual members

Comment: Implementation defined behavior is implementation defined. I didn't say it can't correspond to the size of the largest member, I said it need not. Its a hardware question.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: That makes sense ... thanks for clarifying it

Answer (score 2):

```
int marks[10,5];
```

should be

```
int marks[10][5];
```

There may also be issues of padding and alignment to consider.

Answer (score 2):

If using Visual C++, add [`#pragma pack(1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28VS.80%29.aspx) to the top of your source file to eliminate struct padding.  Default for VC++ is 8 byte boundary.

gcc and other compilers will have their own equivalents.

Comment: Note that this will hurt performance when accessing struct members, and is not probably not worth the 3 bytes you save.

Comment: @rjh: It can have worse effects than that.  I've seen Windows API functions fail when passed a LPWSZ that isn't even-aligned.

Comment: Yes, this is a touchy subject.  Having data properly aligned allows hardware processes like DMA to fetch blocks of data at a time.  If the struct unnecessarily crosses this boundary, two fetches will need to be made instead.  Using pack(1) is handy when you're working with file format structs and are only doing file I/O and need the `sizeof()` operator to give accurate sizes.